# Nested Ternary Conditionals in ng-class

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have a nested ternary condition inside of an ng-class?

#### Works

`ng-class={{ false ? 'uno' : 'dos' }}`
< Outputs dos

#### Doesn't Work

`ng-class={{ false ? 'uno' ? false 'dos' : 'tres' }}`

Comment: First of all, there should be no curly-brace: ng-class expects an expression. But your second example is not valid syntax: if you have two ternary conditions, there should be two `?`and two `:`. There is just one `:`. So that can't be correct.

Comment: ok roger that, thanks for the help

Comment: `{{ false ? 'uno' : (false ? 'dos' : 'tres') }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
ng-class={{ false ? 'uno' : true ?  'dos' : 'tres' }}
```